# Tableau : how to do sql equivalent of group by and partition

Tags: group-by, tableau-api

newbie here; have spent almost a day reading various websites and tips but still getting no where

how does one do a sql equivalent of group by and obtaining only 1 row per partition in tableau?

Basically I have a table of the following, and I am trying to calculate the average duration.  Average duration is taking the difference between startdate and enddate of a call and averaging all calls.  Partition would be the call id

```
 Call_ID  services     StartDate             EndDate
    1       A           10:00am              10:30am
    1       B           10:00am              10:30am
    2       A           10:42am              10:52am
    2       B           10:42am              10:52am
    2       C           10:42am              10:52am
```

In the above example, the average duration would be 20 minutes
Right now, I can calculate the duration for each ROW

```
DATEDIFF('minute', [StartDate], [EndDate])
```

Tableau would show the average as 18 minutes, which is not correct.

I am stuck at how to obtain only one duration per Call ID.

Any assistance is really appreciated

Comment: What should the result look like for above in Tableau

Answer (score 1):

With the data sample you provided, the following would result in an average of 20 minutes.

```
avg({fixed [Call Id]: AVG(DATEDIFF('minute', [Start], [End]))})
```

This uses Level of Detail function. A new feature of Tableau 9.0 and up.

Comment: Thanks Bernardo.  That works :)Now got a follow up question, and not sure if I should be posting this in a separate thread.
 
How would you go about calculating the down time between call id 1 and call id 2? ie. the difference between call id 1 end date and call id 2 start date?
 
I read that using data blending will get you the difference between 2 rows of data? though in this case, start date and end date are 2 different columns.  Is data blending the only method?  and if so, I am puzzled how by the execution method? and if not, what's the alternative calculation method?

Comment: I used custom SQL instead of data blending. This allows the ability to place start and end times in the same column. Then you can do a datediff between the calls depending on whether the call id differs or not. See the attached workbook (9.0) for the details. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/so%20duration.twbx